# Relation between continuity of $f$ and analyticity of $f(z)^8$

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, analyticity

If $f(z)$ is continuous on some domain $D$ and $f(z)^8$ (the function to the eighth power, not the eighth derivative) is analytic, then why does this imply that f is analytic on a neighborhood of each $z_0$ where $f(z_0)\not= 0$? Does this have to do with every branch cut of $z^a$ must go through the origin?

My reasoning is that at each point $z_0,f(z_0)\not=0,\in C$ an appropriate branch cut can be made so $z^{1/8}$ is defined there (just square root four times) and so analytic at each individual point where  $f(z_0)\not=0$. Since $f$ is continuous, would this imply there is an entire neighborhood where this is true somehow? And then these zeros would be isolated, right?

Comment: Your reasoning is sound! The only obstacle to making it a rigorous argument is finding a technical condition that captures your intuition: the eight branches of $z \mapsto z^{1/8}$ are disjoint and so any continuous function must stay "within" a branch and thus be analytic. I want to say something about "Riemann surfaces" or "sheaves" or "local homeomorphisms", but I'm not sure if you're familiar with any of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Claim:** If $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is continuous. and $f^2\in H(\Omega)$. Let $C:=\{z\in \Omega| f(z)=0\}$ ($C$ is closed because $f$ is continuous), then $f|\Omega-C\in H(\Omega-C)$.

Proof: Let $z_0\in \Omega-C$. $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{f(z)^2-f(z_0)^2}{z-z_0}$ exists (Call this limit $L$). Using the continuity of $f$ and the fact that $f(z_0)$ is non-zero, one can show that $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{1}{f(z)+f(z_0)}$ exists as well. Hence, $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}[\frac{f(z)^2-f(z_0)^2}{z-z_0}\frac{1}{f(z)+f(z_0)}]$ and we get:
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}[\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}]=\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}[\frac{f(z)^2-f(z_0)^2}{z-z_0}\frac{1}{f(z)+f(z_0)}]=\,\,\,$$$$lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{f(z)^2-f(z_0)^2}{z-z_0}\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{1}{f(z)+f(z_0)}=\frac{L}{2f(z_0)}$$

Hence $f|\Omega-C$ is analytic on $\Omega-C$ $\square$

Now going back to your question: Since $f$ is continuous, therefore $f^4$ is continuous. Since $(f^4)^2=f^8$ is analytic. By the previous claim, we get $f^4$ is analytic.

Since $f$ is continuous, therefore $f^2$ is continuous. Since $(f^2)^2=f^4$ is analytic. By the previous claim, we get $f^2$ is analytic.

We use the previous claim, for the third time to deduce that $f$ is analytic (because $f$ is continuous and because $f^2$ is analytic as we showed earlier) $\square$

Comment: It is better to infer the structure of $C$ from the analyticity, rather than continuity. Then we get that the set is discrete, not just closed. Eventually this allows us to remove the singularities... And of course this generalizes to other powers, not just those that are powers of 2.

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills The same method I used can be used for other exponents  as well.